# JAVA doesnt allow me to create ActionListener class

Tags: java, actionlistener

Why this code doesn't work? It doesnt allow me to create the "test" class.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    public test() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    }


}
```

Comment: this error ????

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("*why isn't this code working?*") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 0):

When you implement an interface in Java (in this case `ActionListener`), you must either declare your class abstract, or provide an implementation of every method defined on that interface. In other words, you can do either:

```
public class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public test() {
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
    }
}
```

or

```
public abstract class test extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    public test() {
    }
}
```